# Saving Excel File by cell value and saving in current directory where the file was opened

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get this code to save to the directory where the file was opened. At current it manages to save the file by cel text but by default wants to save in c:/my documents.

This is what i have so far and have no idea where to add ThisWorkbook.Path

```
Sub Save()

 Dim flToSave As Variant
 Dim flName As String
 Dim flFormat As Long

 flFormat = ActiveWorkbook.FileFormat


 flName = Range("A1") & Range("A2").Text
 flToSave = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
 (flName, filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", _
 Title:="Save FileAs...")


 If flToSave = False Then
 Exit Sub
 Else

 Thisworkbook.SaveAs Filename:=flToSave, FileFormat:=flFormat
 End If

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `GetSaveAsFilename` to

```
flToSave = Application.GetSaveAsFilename _
(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & flName, filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm", _
Title:="Save FileAs...")
```

This starts the `SaveAs` in the specified directory

Comment: If i may also ask: I have cashup files that have certain links..December takes info from certain files in November. Would it be possible that when i open December to auto collect links from November with out having to change "=+'C:\Stores\Fego Caffe Irene\Cash Ups\2011\[Fego Caffe June 2011.xlsm]Daily Breakdown'!$E$42" everytime i save a new month. so if i create a January file it must auto link to December without me having to manually change it the whole time??

Comment: Have a look at `Workbook.ChangeLink` - if you need help, post another question